# Design approach for "user already exist"

Tags: algorithm

I'm building registration page. One field is nickname and I want to validate it if already exists whenever a user try to register.
I know that validation could be an ajax call from client side, but my question aims to the backend.

Which could be the steps to validate existence of nicknames avoiding too many calls to DB and don't taking too much response time ? imagine that DB's table that contains nickname's data is too large.

Using a cache that contains replicated data of nicknames and updating it when a user successfully can register , is a good approach?

I want to replicate this behavior
https://disqus.com/admin/signup/

Suggestions of any kind are welcome.

Comment: If you have an index on the `nickname` column, the query shouldn't be expensive.

Comment: Responsive design tag is used for UI design, so I removed it.

Comment: @Barmar Yes , but what about more than 120M~140M records?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Indexes mean you don't have to search all the records, they get you directly to the one you want.

Answer (score 2):

1) First Create a procedure like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertUser
@vUserName varchar(50)
,@Password varchar(50)
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tblUsers WHERE vUsername=@vUserName AND        vPassword=@Password)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO tblUsers(vUsername, vPassword) VALUES(vUserName , Password)
SELECT @@IDENTITY
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT -500
END
```

2) Write functions to call this SP

```
public int InsertUser(string vUserName, string vPassword) 
        {
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = null;
            try
            {
                con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("strConnectionString");
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("InsertUser", con);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vUserName", vUserName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", vPassword);

                con.Open();

                object res = null;

                res = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                con.Close();
                return res != null ? Convert.ToInt32(res) : 0;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally { con.Close(); }
        }

        public void RegisterUser(string vUserName, string vPassword) 
        {
            try
            {
                int res = InsertUser(vUserName, vPassword);
                if (res > 0) 
                {
                    //user registered successgully
                }
                else if (res == 0) 
                {
                    // a logical error occured in query
                }
                else if (res == -500) 
                {
                    //user already exists. Please try another
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Catch Exception here
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could keep a hash table of all nicknames that way you only need to compare it with those nicknames that have same hash value.

Comment: That's not bad.  Considering security, you certainly don't want this hashtable to reach the client (then they have a list of all your usernames).  With that in mind, cache your hashtable on the server, perform first look-up against that, and verify with a query to the database.  Updating the hashtable could be scheduled by time, or - if you have tons of simultaneous registrants - based on the frequency of verification queries.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a SQL database? If so, then you'd normally have an `unique` index on the `Users` table's `username` field. This gives you two benefits: ensures data integrity (not possible to have 2 users with same username) and allows the database to quickly responds to queries like `select * from Users where username = "kos"`.